# What is the right embedding between $C^{\infty}_c (\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

There exists an embedding relation “$\subset$” or “$\supset$” between $C^{\infty}_c (\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Could anyone give me an example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: PS if theres anything you want me to expand on with proofs or pictures etc, I'll be glad to. Also: your previous question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601991/is-this-dense-embedding-true with basic modifications (as indicated by a comment) here gives the density of $C^1_c$ in $H^1(\mathbb R^N)$. $C^\infty_c$ is of course dense in $C^1_c$. And your question from  > 1 year ago seems like it covers this question and more https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168100/f-in-c-0-infty-rightarrow-f-in-lm

Comment: It is enough for now, thank You so much @Calvin Khor!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth compactly supported function has weak derivatives of all order that are in every $L^p$ space. In particular,
$$ C^\infty_c (\mathbb R^n)\subset H^1(\mathbb R^n).$$
In fact more is true, $C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ is [dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047652/density-of-smooth-compactly-supported-functions-in-sobolev-space-over-unbounded) in $H^1(\mathbb R^n)$. A $C^1_c$ function that is not smooth shows that $H^1\neq C^\infty_c$.

"bump functions" are your standard example of a function in $C^\infty_c$, and there's lots of discussion on them already on MSE. For example : [Where can we find examples of smooth functions with compact support? Is there a book?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/799567/where-can-we-find-examples-of-smooth-functions-with-compact-support-is-there-a). This example is related to the smooth but non-analytic function in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function).

These examples are for 1 variable but it is trivial to modify them for higher dimensions by e.g. forcing them to be radially symmetric, or multiplying toegether one for each coordinate.